# jqGrid - Undefined index: native_type ...eval()'d code on line 1

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I got this error!

Undefined index: native_type in C:\wamp\www\avr\php\jqGridPdo.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 1..

This works fine in my machine but when I upload and test it in the linux server I got the error message (the grid works perfectly though)...Am I missing any configuration here..?

The codes can be found here...http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=595&#post595

Please help!

thx

Answer (score 0):

Check the versions of php being run - could be related to this.

Comment: are the versions different between he server and your test machine?